# Infinite loop using __getattr__ and getattr

Tags: python, python-2.7, infinite, getattr

Okay, I'm having a bit of a problem and I'm not quite sure why its occurring the way that it is. What I'm trying to do is allow access to attributes on an object via snake_case or camelCase in python 2.7.X I thought that `__getattr__` was the correct way to do this, but clearly I'm mistaken and I'm not ex

So here's my simplified implementation. In this scenario, no matter what attribute you access, I want `foo.x` to be returned.

```
class Foo(object):
  def __init__(self, x):
    self.x = x

  def __getattr__(self, name):
    if hasattr(self, name):
      return getattr(self, name)
    elif hasattr(self, 'x'):
      return getattr(self, 'x')
    else:
      raise AttributeError, n
```

Now if I do:

```
f = Foo('myX')
f.x             
# => "myX"
```

However, I don't understand why:

```
f.y
```

Loops forever. Interestingly, when I put `print "__getattr__ called with : %s" % name` at the first line of the `__getattr__`, it appears that when `f.y` gets called, the `getattr(self, 'x')` line does actually get called, but then it doesn't look like getattr is ever actually called with 'x' instead, `__getattr__` still says that it is getting called with "y."

I've been looking around, and I think it has something to do with my misunderstanding of how the `getattr` works. Any advice or documentation that you all have to point me to would be very beneficial. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `getattr(self, 'x')` is exactly equivalent to `self.x` - it doesn't go directly to the default attribute lookup mechanism or do anything at all different from `self.x`. You've probably misunderstood what `hasattr` and `getattr` do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`hasattr()` is implemented as a call to `getattr()` and returns `False` if an exception was raised.

`__getattr__` is only called if your instance doesn't have the attribute; it is a fallback. Using `hasattr()` in `__getattr__` is entirely pointless.

Since `f.x` exists, `Foo.__getattr__` is never called. `f.y` does not exist, so `Foo.__getattr__(f, 'y')` is called, which calls `hasattr(f, 'y')` which calls `getattr(f, 'y')` which calls `Foo.__getattr__(f, 'y')` because the `y` attribute doesn't exist, etc.

From the [`object.__getatt__()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__):

> Called when an attribute lookup has not found the attribute in the usual places (i.e. it is not an instance attribute nor is it found in the class tree for self).

and from the [`hasattr()` function documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hasattr):

> (This is implemented by calling `getattr(object, name)` and seeing whether it raises an exception or not.)

Comment: Thank you very much for you response. This makes sense now. Its interesting that hasattr is implemented like that, but I suppose it makes sense. I'll accept your answer and I'm going to write an implementation that does work below.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to post a working implementation of my snake/camelCase problem that I spoke of at the beginning. Check out @Martijn's answer for an explanation as to why this works and the old one fails.

```
class Foo(object):

def __init__(self, x):
  self.x = x

def __getattr__(self, name):
  #if hasattr(self, name)     # As Martijn pointed out, this call is completely
  #  getattr(self, name)      # useless in this context because the only reason
                              # you are even in __getattr__ is because self
                              # does not have the attribute. This call is what
                              # was causing the infinite loop.
  components = name.split('_')
  camel_case = components[0] + "".join(x.title() for x in components[1:])
  if hasattr(self, camel_case):
    return getattr(self, camel_case)
  else:
    raise AttributeError, name
```